# How to use a IPv6 link-local address with Retrofit as baseUrl

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, ipv6

I'm using the [NsdManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager) to resolve a service on the local network (iot device). The [resolveService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager#resolveService(android.net.nsd.NsdServiceInfo,%20android.net.nsd.NsdManager.ResolveListener)) returns me a [NsdServiceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdServiceInfo) with a host and a port. The host is a [Inet6Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address?hl=en) object with a link-local address (fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:9718) and no scope set. It also returns me a true for [isLinkLocalAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address?hl=en#isLinkLocalAddress()). **How can I use this link-local address without a scope to make any network call**?

The only way I can ping the service with my local machine is by also specifying a network interface e.g. like this: `ping6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:9718%en0`.

It feels like I'm missing some vital aspect of the Android API or the IPv6 spec here. **Personally, I'd rather just get a IPv4 address but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell the NsdManager that either.**

Answer (score 1):

you can try to retrieve the name of the interface programmatically using the NetworkInterface class from the Java networking API. For example:

```
val interfacename = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    .toList()
    .find { interface ->
        interface.inetAddresses.any { address ->
            address is Inet6Address && address.isLinkLocalAddress
        }
    }
    ?.name

val baseUrl = "http://[fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:9718%$interfacename]:port/"

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .build()
```

Comment: Turns out Retrofit/OkHttp doesn't support link-local addresses with scope. PR rejected here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/4865. This might work with other libraries though.

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that IPv6 Link-Local addresses have specific uses, and are not typically used for normal network traffic.

From *[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html)*:

> Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a
> single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration,
> neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present.

Next, because all interfaces in a device use the same Link-Local network, you must use a Zone ID to distinguish the interface meant for the destination. Remember that even hosts (PCs, printers, etc.) have routing tables, so they must distinguish Link-Local addresses using Zone IDs.

From *[RFC 6874, Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6874)*:

> Because the same non-global address may be in use in more than one
> zone of the same scope (e.g., the use of link-local address fe80::1 in
> two separate physical links) and a node may have interfaces attached
> to different zones of the same scope (e.g., a router normally has
> multiple interfaces attached to different links), a node requires an
> internal means to identify to which zone a non-global address belongs.
> This is accomplished by assigning, within the node, a distinct "zone
> index" to each zone of the same scope to which that node is attached,
> and by allowing all internal uses of an address to be qualified by a
> zone index.

Use of a Zone ID for IPv6 Link-Local addressing is a requirement. In fact, Link-Local addressing is currently the only allowed use of Zone IDs.

From *[RFC 6874, Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6874)*:

> To limit this risk, implementations MUST NOT allow use of this format
> except for well-defined usages, such as sending to link-local
> addresses under prefix fe80::/10.  At the time of writing, this is the
> only well-defined usage known.

You could use some other unique addressing, e.g. ULA (*[RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193)*), to avoid that requirement. For ULA, you use addressing in the `fc00::/7` range, with restrictions that limit you to the `fd00::/8` range, where the next 40 bits must be randomly chosen, giving you a `/48` prefix from which you get 65,536 standard `/64` IPv6 networks.